# Sending all outgoing TCP packets through Tor

Tags: 11.04, command-line

I want to make all outgoing TCP packets on my Ubuntu 10.04 computer anonymous. Is this possible? If so, how would I configure my computer to do this?

I've installed Tor, but it doesn't work because I'm running my computer strictly from command line. Could protecting my identity be achieved another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [these instructions on using Tor as a transparent proxy](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy).